# Regex to find missing ConfigureAwait

Tags: regex, visual-studio, async-await, configureawait

I have a specific pattern that I want to search for in Visual Studio.

Basically, I want to search for lines that contains `await`, but are missing `ConfigureAwait` at the end of the statement.

I have some patterns that works in regex-testers such as regex101.com, but I can't get these patterns to work in Visual Studio search. For example, the pattern `(?s)^(.)*(await)((?!ConfigureAwait).)*(.)?(;)`.

What I am doing wrong?

Edit - I want to find lines in my project such as

`await DoSomeCoolThings(x, y);` (i.e. missing the `ConfigureAwait(...)`.)

but I don't want to get a match for lines such as:

`await DoSomeCoolThings(x, y).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Remove the `/.../`... What does the input look like? Please post some sample string or share a link to the online tester fiddle at least. Also, remove `(?s)` and replace `.` with `[\s\S\r]`. Note that `(.)*` is a bad approach to quantifying groups - as one symbol is captured infinite number of times, it creates redundant overhead for the regex engine. Use `(.*)` (if you need to capture at all). I think most of the capture groups are redundant here (until you clarify what you are doing).

Comment: `(?=.*await)(?!.*ConfigureAwait)` should also work

Comment: Sorry, the slashes are not part of the pattern. I've removed them from my example pattern.

Comment: @rock321987 - this works. Thank you!

Comment: glad, it worked for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the order of `await` and `ConfigureAwait` does not matter, then you can use

```
(?=.*\bawait\b)(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b)
```

otherwise, if you consider that `ConfigureAwait` should come after `await`, you can use

```
(?=.*\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b))
```

**Efficient Solution**

```
(?=\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b))
```

Comment: I wonder how `ConfigureAwait` can come before `await` :) That first unanchored lookahead is unnecessary complication here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was thinking it from regex point of view..:)

Comment: If the document is large, your regex will slow down matching because the unanchored lookarounds are checked *at each and every location in the text*. You see, in my expression, the whole line is grabbed first, then, backtracking finds the `await`, and then the negative lookahead triggers. In your case, the engine checks the beginning of the string: grabs all, backtracks, finds or not, triggered the negative lookahead, and goes on like this at each location, before each character. It is highly inefficient, and is bad practice when *global matching* is involved (like here, `/g` is implied).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wait..but the debugger mode does not says so..can you please clarify a bit more

Comment: (I guess I removed my comment): Sorry, I meant highlighting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can compare my second regex with yours.. First one is inefficient :- I agree, but its for checking if one word is present and other is not anywhere in the string

Comment: The second one is of the same  structure (unanchored lookaround). You know regex101 - you can quickly see the difference there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am using that site only for the comparison..There is only a difference of two steps between my second regex and yours even in the case of no match

Comment: See the regex debugger with PCRE. And all depends on the input string as usual. BTW, `.*?\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b).*` - 45 steps, and [`(?=.*\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b))`](https://regex101.com/r/qT4qN6/1) - 83.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was comparing `.*\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b).*` regex which you have written initially, and it takes `82` steps..If I modify my regex to `(?=\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b))`, it takes `45` steps

Comment: Cool. I just though that a *line* must be matched that is why I used consuming `.*`. Those may really be unnecessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's what I was thinking..also I can use lazy quantifier(as you have used) in my regex and it will work again with difference of two steps

Answer (score 2):

I do not think we should be constrained to a single line, as more complicated statements can be split up into multiple lines. Also, the solution should preferably be fast.

To that effect, we can either use the Resharper plugin "ConfigureAwait Checker", or the following regex:

```
\bawait\b(?![^;]*ConfigureAwait)[^;]*;
```

The idea is to find the word "await", and then read the entire statement until its semicolon `;`, matching only if the word "ConfigureAwait" is missing in that text. More specifically:

1. `\bawait\b`: Whole word "await".
2. `(?!...)`: Negative lookahead that we will use to exclude matches that already have ConfigureAwait.

   - `[^;]*ConfigureAwait`: The word "ConfigureAwait", preceded by any number of characters that are not the semicolon.
3. `[^;]*`: Any number of characters that are not the semicolon.
4. The semicolon.

I got a few minor false positives where the statement contains a query string (with a semicolon) or a lambda (with a semicolon). They were so easily ignored that I did not find it worthwhile to further complicate the regex.

Answer (score 1):

To match these lines with `await` but without `ConfigureAwait` after it, you can use a  simpler negative lookahead based regex:

```
.*\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b).*
```

The pattern matches any non-newline symbols (`.*`) followed with a whole word `await` (as `\b` are word boundaries) and then a check is performed to make sure there is no whole word `ConfigureAwait` somewhere after `await` (with a lookahead `(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b)`), and then the rest of line is matched with `.*`.

[image]

Since `await` is usually close to the left side of the string, best is to use a lazy dot matching at the beginning:

```
.*?\bawait\b(?!.*\bConfigureAwait\b).*
```